# Subring with maximal ideals (prime avoidance). Proof verifying and small question

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, ideals

> Let $t∈\Bbb N$ and let $p_1, \dots ,p_t$ be $t$ distinct prime numbers. Show that
>   $$R = \{α∈\Bbb Q : α = m/n \mbox{ for some } m ∈ \Bbb Z \mbox{ and } n∈\Bbb N \mbox{ such that } n \mbox{ is divisible by none of } p_1, \dots ,p_t\}$$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q$ which has exactly $t$ maximal ideals.

My poor solution is:

choose n=P(t+1)<- (t+1) is index of P.
then any of pi divides P(t+1)
for m ∈ Z, α=m/P(t+1) at least α∈R, So, R= ⁄∅

1st subring condition.
α1∈R,α2∈Q,m1,m2∈Z,n1,n2∈ N
choose n1=p(k+1),n2=p(k+2) k>t (to keep indivisibility of n1,n2)
Let, α1=m1/n1 and α2=m2/n2
α1-α2==m1/n1-m2/n2=(m1n2-m2n1)/n1n2 (indivisibility holds as n1,n2 primes n1n2 cant divide any of other prime numbers)
(m1n2-m2n1)∈Z can be seen clearly.
α1-α2∈R (by definiton)
2nd subring condition.
Let α=m/n∈R q∈Q 
again n=P(t+1) to keep indivisibility

αq?∈R
α=mq/n
let q=r/s r∈Z,s∈Z

1.case r>m ==> rm/sn?∈R yes. If n indivisiple then sn is. 
rm∈Z is clear. because we choose.
2.case r rm/sn?∈R If n indivisiple then sn is. 
Let m=st ,
rm/sn=r(st)/

i messed up because i dont know if s is factor of m or not.
and i have no connection with maximal ideals.
i need comments to verify my proof.

thanks

Comment: Your question is a particular case of localization at the complement of a union of finitely many prime ideals.

Comment: but it is from R.Y. Sharp ex.3.67 (Prime and maximal ideals section) after prime avoidance theorem. and i have no idea about localization :S